# launchctl: Error unloading: org.apache.httpd

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx

I just upgraded my OS to Mountain Lion and found that my local server wasn't working anymore. As I began to work through trying to fix that, I found that running `sudo apachectl stop` returns `launchctl: Error unloading: org.apache.httpd`

What does this mean, and how do I fix it?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`launchctl:` is shown because `apachectl` is using `launchd`'s control script, `launchctl`, to start and stop Apache.

`Error unloading` means the given daemon/service of `launchd` can not be stopped. This usually happens if the given daemon is already stopped.

`org.apache.httpd` is the name of the plist file defining how httpd is run by `launchd`. If you are curious the actual plist is at

```
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
```

---

If the server is merely off just use:

```
sudo apachectl start
```

to get it running again.

Otherwise I would check system.log (you can use Console.app) and see if there are any, more informative, error messages.

Answer (score 3):

try running the following command to see more verbosely what errors you're getting

```
sudo bash -x /usr/sbin/apachectl -k stop
```