# starting nginx on mac fails with 48: address already in use

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, mac-osx

I'm trying to start nginx on my Mac OS X using the command `sudo nginx`

It fails with the following error

```
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:8080 failed (48: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:8080 failed (48: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:8080 failed (48: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:8080 failed (48: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:8080 failed (48: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
```

I try to stop the Apache service by using `sudo apachectl stop`

This throws me the following error

```
launchctl: Error unloading: org.apache.httpd
```

According to [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/413529) it most likely means that Apache is already not running

Then I tried to figure what is running on the Port 80 using `sudo lsof -i:80`

This outputs to this

```
Google    441 jaskaran   68u  IPv4 0xa3f4d891ed1a8373      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.45:50993->www.google:http (ESTABLISHED)
Google    441 jaskaran  143u  IPv4 0xa3f4d891ed054b5b      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.45:51017->www.scorecardresearch.com:http (ESTABLISHED)
Google    441 jaskaran  150u  IPv4 0xa3f4d891eb9a1b5b      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.45:51018->www.scorecardresearch.com:http (ESTABLISHED)
Google    441 jaskaran  152u  IPv4 0xa3f4d891ed1a4373      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.45:51019->www.scorecardresearch.com:http (ESTABLISHED)
Google    441 jaskaran  156u  IPv4 0xa3f4d891ed071b5b      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.45:51020->www.scorecardresearch.com:http (ESTABLISHED)
```

The output to this command keeps on changing with time.

How do I get nginx to work?

Comment: Note that you get an error regarding port 8080 (`bind() to 0.0.0.0:8080`) so you should check which process is listening on that, not on 80. Use `lsof -i:8080` or `sudo netstat -a -n | grep 80` to find the blocking process

Comment: Also, the `lsof` command shows both incoming & outgoing connections on the listed port; the results you're seeing are outgoing connections to port 80 on various remote servers, not activity on your server's port 80.

Comment: @LightningIsMyName lsof -i:8080 shows no output. I tried changing the port from 8080 to 80 in my nginx.conf file but I'm still getting the same error. Any suggestions?

Comment: When you change to port 80, are you running nginx as root? It's required to bind to port 80. Also, if you run ps aux|grep -i apache do you see any apache processes running? How about ps aux|grep http ? If it says something is bound to a port, it generally is because something is, I can't say that I've seen an anomaly to this.

Comment: This usually means you have 2 conflicting listen statements throughout your config somewhere.  Do a grep -i listen in all your config directories.

Comment: Can you post your nginx.conf ?

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/a/488491/67675

(For Mac OS X `lsof` part is relevant.)

Answer (score 1):

Before attempting to start `nginx`, check if something is already running on port '8080' as follows. I say port "8080", because that's the port number shown in the error message you posted:

`$ sudo netstat -nlp | grep ':8080'
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2355/nginx

tcp6       0      0 :::8080                   :::*                    LISTEN      2355/nginx`

In my case, that's showing a process named "nginx" with the Process ID of 2355 running on port 8080.

You try can issuing a `kill -TERM 2355` to the related process ID to get to stop (assuming you don't want it running), and then confirm with `netstat`, as shown above. Change "2355" to match your own process ID.

You may *still* get the error even if you've confirmed that nothing is running on that part before you try to start to `nginx`. In that case, your Nginx may have conflicting entries regarding that port. Search your Nginx configuration for `8080`. If there are multiple mentions, review the docs for the related configuration to confirm you haven't used it too many times.